# How to center the caption of a grid

Tags: jqgrid

How to center the caption of a grid without changing the css (which is global) ?
By defaut the caption is on left.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the code which center the caption could be about the following

```js
$("#grid").closest("div.ui-jqgrid-view")
    .children("div.ui-jqgrid-titlebar")
    .css("text-align", "center")
    .children("span.ui-jqgrid-title")
    .css("float", "none");
```

See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CenterTitle.htm):

[image]

Comment: Don't forget this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299151/grid-height-and-the-empty-space-after-the-last-column

Comment: @Bertaud: One needs time for the question, but I am busy this week. :-(

Comment: @Oleg can you help me out with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361083/getting-value-of-a-column-on-click-of-a-row-in-jqgrid ,, thanks

Comment: thanks Oleg. what if i want to change the font size of the caption as well ? i tried

Comment: $("#list").closest("div.ui-jqgrid-view")
     .children("div.ui-jqgrid-titlebar")
     .css("text-align", "center",
       "font-size","20px")
     .children("span.ui-jqgrid-title")
     .css("float", "none");

Comment: @user2334092: You are welcome! you can use just `caption` value as HTML fragment with another font-size like `caption: '<span style="font-size:20px">Demonstrate how to center the title of the grid</span>'`

Comment: Oleg, i am trying '<span style="font-size:20px; text-align:center;">Title</span>'

Comment: but it does not work. the font size changes but the title still appears on the left

Comment: @user2334092: You should combine the suggestion from the answer (which center the caption) with the usage of `caption: "<span style="font-size:20px">Demonstrate how to center the title of the grid</span>"` (which changes the font size of the grid title)

Answer (score 0):

It's been awhile since this question was raised and answered. Another approach would be:

```
<style>
.ui-jqgrid-caption {
  text-align:center !important;
}
</style>
```